# The constructor of function 01-deploy-fund-me.js expect 1 argument but got 42

Tags: contract-deployment, javascript, hardhat, rinkeby

I am at moment 10:59:00 in the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ&list=PLMippBqdcHKavY7WqPnoWbRgkgjn0dq9v&index=27&t=297s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org, I try tu run:

```
 yarn hardhat deploy --network rinkeby
```

and it returns me this:

```
Error: ERROR processing /home/nachoddiaz/Curso32/hardhat-fund-me/deploy/01-deploy-fund-me.js:
Error: expected 1 constructor arguments, got 42
```

Here is my code:

### 01-deploy-fund-me.js

```
const { networkConfig, devChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config.js")
const { getNamedAccounts, deployments, network } = require("hardhat")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify.js")

//Podemos resumir las dos lineas anteriores en una sola
module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
  const chainId = network.config.chainId

  let ETHUSDPriceAddress //ponemos let para poder actualiarla
  if (devChains.includes(network.name)) {
    //Si estamos en devChain, desplegamos mock
    const ETHUSDAgregator = await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator")
    ETHUSDPriceAddress = ETHUSDAgregator.address
  } else {
    //Si no estamos en devChain, desplegamos normal
    ETHUSDPriceAddress = networkConfig[chainId]["ETHUSDPrice"]
  }

  const args = ETHUSDPriceAddress

  //cuando trabajemos localhost o en la red hardhat, usaremos un mock
  const fundMe = await deploy("FundMe", {
    from: deployer,
    args: args, // estos argumentos se le pasan al constructor
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1
  })

  if (!devChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
    await verify(fundMe.address, args)
  }
  log(
    "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
  )
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "fundme"]
```

### hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("hardhat-deploy")
require("dotenv").config()
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")

const Rinkeby_URL = process.env.Rinkeby_RPC_URL
const PRIVATE_KEY_RINKEBY = process.env.Private_KEY
const CMC_API_KEY = process.env.CMCAPI
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY

module.exports = {
  //solidity: "0.8.9",
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: Rinkeby_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY_RINKEBY],
      chainId: 4,
      blockConfirmations: 6 // esperamos 6 para que a etherscan le de tiempo a indexar nuestra TX
    }
  },
  solidity: {
    compilers: [{ version: "0.8.8" }, { version: "0.6.6" }]
  },
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  gasReporter: {
    enabled: true,
    outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
    noColors: true,
    currency: "USD",
    coinmarketcap: CMC_API_KEY,
    token: "MATIC"
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  },
  namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: 0
    },
    users: {
      default: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help and sorry for my english level

Answer (score 1):

`args` should be an array but you only assign it to `ETHUSDPriceAddress`. You can try `args = [ETHUSDPriceAddress]`.